# how to subtract rows in a data frame in R depending on difference between values?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I have a data frame that is in the following format

```
df <- data.frame(name=LETTERS[1:5], location=c(2000,2021,4532,1931,3457),
                 value=c(1,0,1,1,0))

name    location   value
A       2000       1
B       2021       0
C       4532       1
D       1931       1
E       3457       0
```

There are approximately a million rows in the data frame. How would I create a new dataframe that has the distance between every location if the locations are within 1000 of each other also checks to see if the values are both one for both locations?

For the above dataset, the dataframe would only have three rows in it with values of 21 (absolute value of 2000 - 2021), 69 (absolute value of 2000 - 1931), and 90 (abs. value of 2021-1931) because those are the only differences that are less than 1000. It would also have a column of 0 (because A and B values are not 1 and 1), 1 (because A and C values are 1 and 1), and 0 (because B and C are not 1 and 1). So it would look like:

```
21   0
69   1
90   0
```

I've tried using loops but since there are so many rows, it's inefficient. Is there some built in function that I should use to do this faster? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm surprised that you don't seem to want any labels in the output. Do you not care to know the names corresponding to the rows in your output?

Comment: First, it seems obvious to sort (order) the dataframe by increasing `location`. Then the distance column is simply `diff(location)`. Then you can do the rest using a sliding-window of +/- 1000 on `location` column.

Comment: @smci Not if there are many (>2) locations close to each-other. That actually happens in the example data.

Comment: @Renu: it does make it simpler because we can use simple logical indexing: to create a window of +/- 1000 on `location`, excluding given row. Then we could use sapply/ dplyr / data.table aggregation over that window. I never said the window would contain only one member.

Comment: @smci I'm skeptical you'll get standard grouping tools to work well. If you have locations 2000, 2050, and 2120, you don't have a mutually exclusive grouper. Maybe `rollapply` has something for this? If I were to do an R solution I would emulate renu's answer with non-equi joins in data.table.

Comment: By the way, in your example you only want consecutive locations. So DA,AB,EC but not DB,DE,AE. But you said *"the distance between every location if the locations are within 1000 "*. So which is it?

Answer (score 4):

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("
select  a.location
        , b.location
        , a.location - b.location as locdiff
        , a.value*b.value as value
from    df a
        inner join df b
          on a.location - b.location between 1 and 1000
")
```

This gives

```
  a.location b.location locdiff value
1       2000       1931      69     1
2       2021       2000      21     0
3       2021       1931      90     0
```

Or with `data.table`. This is just @MKR's solution but adding a column to avoid a large join result. Not sure if it's possible to achieve this without creating a new column.

```
setDT(df)

df[, loc2 :=  location - 1000]

df[df 
  , .( locdiff   = i.location - x.location
     , locationA = i.location
     , locationB = x.location
     , value     = x.value*i.value)
  , on = .(location >= loc2 
          , location < location)
  , nomatch = 0]
```

gives

```
   locdiff locationA locationB value
1:      69      2000      1931     1
2:      90      2021      1931     0
3:      21      2021      2000     0
```

Comment: Great answer. SQL is much better for something like this than doing a million x million join in R and filtering down.

Comment: @Gregor Agree with comment that `sqldf` could be better option and its a great answer. In the meant time I worked on a `data.table` based solution in which I tried to minimize cartesian join by joining on `x.location > i.location`.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Gregor comment where he mentioned `sqldf` to be better option to in above scenario in the sense that it avoid cartesian join of million records.

But I tried to optimize `data.table` based solution by first joining on `x.location > i.location` and then filtering on `diff <=1000`.

```
df <- data.frame(name=LETTERS[1:5], location=c(2000,2021,4532,1931,3457),
                 value=c(1,0,1,1,0))
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[df,.(name, diff = x.location - i.location, value = x.value*i.value), 
         on=.(location > location), nomatch=0][diff<=1000]
#    name diff value
# 1:    B   21     0
# 2:    A   69     1
# 3:    B   90     0
```

Comment: If you add a column `df[, loc_max := location + 1000]` you can add `location < loc_max` to the `on` criteria instead of filtering post-hoc. I'm not sure quite how the internals work, but there's at least a good chance it will be more memory efficient.

Comment: Thanks much for your comments. Let me perform some benchmark on these options. That can give us some useful results.

Comment: @Arun mentions briefly the method `data.table` uses for joins ~10 mins into this video https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/useR-international-R-User-conference/useR2016/Efficient-in-memory-non-equi-joins-using-datatable

Comment: @Renu I think `non-equii` join would be efficient based on details from Arun in his video. Equii join could be faster but in above case there will be overhead to create a column.